# Inner Join or what else?

Tags: sql-server

What I have

```
Table A                                 Table B


ID    ID_Fruit    ,,, so on             ID      ID_Fruit   ID_CRATE  DateTime                
1     1002                              i_1     1002          1      2014-07-28 00:00.000
2     4534                              i_2     1002          2      2014-06-25 00:00.000
3     1243                              i_3     1243          NULL   2014-07-09 00:00.000
4     1003                              i_4     4534          1      2014-07-23 00:00.000`
```

Result I want:

```
ID    ID_Fruit    ,,, so on             ID      ID_Fruit    ID_CRATE     DateTime
1     1002                              i_1     1002           2      2014-06-25 00:00.000
2     4534                              i_4     4534           1      2014-07-23 00:00.000
```

What I am trying,

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLEA
    OUTER APPLY  
        (SELECT * 
         FROM TableB 
         WHERE TableB.ID_Fruit = TableA.ID_Fruit 
           AND TableB.ID_CRATE IS NOT NULL
        ) As Table_B
```

I want only 1 row from several rows in `Table B` based on closest `DateTime`

Comment: Are you saying that if there are multiple rows in table B matching the same ID_Fruit, you only want to return the row with the "highest" or "largest" date?

Comment: @PhilSumner yes that's right 100% thank you

Comment: But `'2014-07-28'` is later than `'2014-06-25'`. Do you want the latest date or the earliest date?

Comment: That's exactly why I asked the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, shouldn't be too difficult, try:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.ID_Fruit,,, so on b.ID, b.ID_Fruit, b.ID_Crate, b.[DateTime]
FROM TABLEA a
INNER JOIN TABLEB b ON a.ID_Fruit = b.ID_Fruit
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID_Fruit, MAX([DateTime]) FROM TABLEB GROUP BY ID_FRUIT) maxtime 
      ON b.[DateTime] = maxtime.[DateTime]
```

Its not quite clear if you mean that it should be the most recent, but I have assumed that is what you mean.

Answer (score -2):

I get the suggestion of @blobbles and rewrite my response.

I divide my answer into two parts for convenience:

1. In the case of table A contains all the `idFruit` of table B or when data quantity are not so big.

   ```
   WITH fruit AS ( 
       SELECT idFruit, MAX (dt) dt
       FROM B
       WHERE b.idCrane IS NOT NULL
       GROUP BY B.idFruit
   )
   SELECT *
   FROM A, B, fruit
   WHERE     a.idFruit = fruit.idFruit
             AND b.idFruit = fruit.idFruit
             AND b.dt = fruit.dt
   ```

   IMVHO it's a more feasible solution.

   This is the simplest case. In case of necessity it's possible add an HINT materialize in the with clause to increase performance.
2. In the case of table A that do not contains all the `idFruit` of table B.

   I think the with block can reduce the resulting record set if the condition between A and B are present.

   ```
   WITH fruit AS ( 
       SELECT B.idFruit, MAX (b.dt) dt
       FROM A, B
       WHERE a.idFruit = B.idFruit 
             AND b.idCrane IS NOT NULL
       GROUP BY B.idFruit
   )
   ```

P.S. I leave the explicit statement between A, B and Fruit instead of `JOIN` just because, to me, it seems easier to read, but I agree with what he says @blobbles in the comments below.

Comment: You do have a join, three joins actually. Without a `JOIN` keyword. And table `A` in the cte is not needed at all. Your query is essentially the same as the one in @blobbles answer.

Comment: Yes, it's right.
I mean without using the JOIN word

the query is similar to that of @blobbles obviously but using a with I thinks it's more nimble, nothing more.

Comment: Edit your answer to take out the unnecessary join in your CTE and I will probably agree with you! It will look nicer, but I recommend explicitly using a JOIN in your outer statement instead of A,B,fruit. The query optimiser will turn these into joins internally anyway, so you may as well say what they are!